# How I add a button in jQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Please help me. How can I add a button in the following jQuery DataTable?

```js
$('#myTable').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/Query/loadData",
    "type": "GET",
    "datatype": "json"
  },      
  "columns": [
    { "data": "Emp_Id", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "Gen", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "EmpName", "autoWidth": true }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>EmpId</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where you want to add the button? In some column, above the table, below the table ?

Comment: After EmpId   at  Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not correct, you have 4 columns in jQuery DataTables definition, 2 columns in table header, and 1 column in table body.

If your data is in HTML, just add code for button (using `<a></a>`, `<input>` or `<button></button>`) in the corresponding cell.

Use delegated event handler to handle click on the button. For example:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('click', '.btn', function(){
   // Get row data
   var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

   alert('Name: ' +  data[0]);
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/89ddvepw/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: i feel this is obvious if you are not doing server side processing, this solution doesnt work for server side